# In which scripture did Shankaracharya mentioned not to say "Aham Brahmasmi"?

Tags: scripture, advaita, identification-request, adi-shankaracharya

I heard that it is not recommended to say "Aham Brahmasmi" in a vague sense. It is because of the reason that Adi Shankaracharya told to split the tongue of one who says "Aham Brahmasmi" without personal experience.

I want to know the name of the scripture in which Adi Shankaracharya says this. What is the name of the scripture in which Adi Shankaracharya asked to split the tongue for trivializing the Vedantic statement?